# Escaping Single Quotes for a String with single quotes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a filename and need to insert into table in SQL Server. I know, I can double up the single quote and insert , but this file name is kinda tricky. 
Any help would be highly appreciated.

@Filename :

```
'013095','013096','013213','013214','013815','013871','013872','13873','013874','013875','013876','013879','13877','13878' 2015-01-24.xls'
```

I know this is a very bad file name provided by clients, but I wanted to give it a try before I can revert it back.

I have tried below two things to achieve this:

1. Use the Replace function to replace single quote by escaping or double up.

   ```
   set @FilenameFinal = Replace(@FileName,char(39), '''')
   ```

My ultimate goal is to get this function correctly to recognize above file name and call this function from a stored procedure which does insert.

```
Set @index = 1
Set @FilenameFinal = ''
set @len = LEN(@FileName)

while @index <= @len
begin
    set @char = Substring(@FileName,@index,1)

    If (@char = char(39))
    begin
        set @char = Replace(@char, char(39),'''')
        --set @filename = Replace(@filename,Char(39),'''')
    end

    --set @FileName = @char + Substring(`enter code here, @index,1)
    set @FilenameFinal = @FileNameFinal + @char 

    set @index = @index + 1
end

return @FilenameFinal
```

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this line instead:

```
set @char = Replace(@char, '''', '''''')
```

This changes all single quotes to doubled quotes (escaped).

You also don't need the WHILE loop.  Just the one line should properly escape things.